# ctags problem when generating tags for .h and .c file in two different directory

Tags: vim, ctags

Now I have two directory, all of header files *.h are included in directory /inc, while all of c file *.c are stored in /src directory.

The directory just like this, (/project is a up level directory):

```
/project-- |----/inc
           |----/src
```

I want to use **ctrl+]** to locate definition of one parameter or one function in a source file like example.c. How to generate those tags?

My method is:

```
(1) cd to the /project directory

(2) ctags inc/*.h src/*.c
```

Then a tags file is generated there, however, when I open a example file and using "Ctrl+]", it cannot lead me to its definition. Why???

Do I need to generate a tags file under /src???

Any help? Many thanks!

Comment: actually, when I use ctags -R under /src directory, it can lead me to some definition in the source files, however, i am not sure whether it can lead me to something which defined in the header file located under /inc directory.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim, try typing:

1. `:pwd`
2. `:set tags`

Verify that the path to your tagfile is present in output of 2, relative to the path that is the output of 1.

NOTE: You can set the `tags` variable as part of your local `.vimrc`.

UPDATE: It is common to set `tags` to a pattern like `tags,../tags,../../tags`.  With this pattern, vim will use the first tags file that it finds your folder structure (again relative to your `pwd`).

Comment: after :set tags  it gives something like this " tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS "...  is it right?

Comment: @MiaTiano: This value of `tags` tells vim to search for the tags file in the same directory that you opened your file.  I bet if you added `../tags` to the search path (as noted in my UPDATE above) it would work for you.  The bottom line is that vim starts looking for the tags from from `pwd`.  The file names it searches for are listed in `:set tags`.

Comment: @MiaTiano: See the documentation of the '-f' option at http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html.  From `ctags`, the output file name "...default is 'tags', or 'TAGS' when running in etags mode".

Answer (score 2):

Go to /project, and use the command "ctags -R ."  In your .vimrc, put the command "set tags=/project/tags".  Exit vim and enter it again.  Tags should now work.

Comment: if I add /project/tags into .vimrc, then everything in the future will affect by this sentence, right?  Besides, /project/tags is part of the path, do I need to add the whole path of set tags=~/abcd/project/tags ??

Comment: Yes, putting it in the .vimrc will affect everything until you remove it.  I have a bunch of tags files separated by commas in my .vimrc.  And yes, you need the full path.  Your question mentioned /project, so I assumed it was the full path.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and kind answer. I have learned a lot from you. :)

Comment: since you are such a expert and Tim may need more reputation, I think you may not mind if my giving accepted answer to Tim. :)

Comment: That's fine.  Whichever answer you found more helpful.